# Could not print time after conversion from string format

Tags: android, simpledateformat

```
 // For Date validation
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String datechosen = dateText.getText().toString() ;
    Date dateselected = simpleDateFormat1.parse(datechosen);
    System.out.println(dateselected);


    // For Time validation
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String timechosen = timeText.getText().toString();
    Date timeselected = simpleDateFormat.parse(timechosen);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(timeselected);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, noofhourselected);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,  noofminselected);
    timeselected = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(timeselected);
```

I am working on converting the string which i have into the date and time format. For example, the string datechosen contain "26/10/2020". I am able to to convert it into date format and print it out.

But for the time string, i am unable to print them out. I am facing the error below:

[Screenshot of the log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40wSt.png)

But if i swap the position of the codes the other way round,

```
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String timechosen = timeText.getText().toString();
    Date timeselected = simpleDateFormat.parse(timechosen);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(timeselected);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, noofhourselected);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,  noofminselected);
    timeselected = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(timeselected);

    // For Date validation
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String datechosen = dateText.getText().toString() ;
    Date dateselected = simpleDateFormat1.parse(datechosen);
    System.out.println(dateselected);
```

The time will be printed instead
[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Inputfield]
These are the two input fields

Comment: Looks you are passing `""` empty string to it. Check your `timeText`.

Comment: It actually contain value but if i tried swapping the positioning of the codes, the time will be printed out and i will receive the following same error for the date instead

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: For your next questions here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please. It makes everything easier for everyone.

Comment: @OleV.V. Alright will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting date in wrong format for time. for `cal.setTime(timeselected);` setTime takes `Date` [Refer java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Use same format as used for Date.

Comment: But my value for the time string is "19:00". Shouldnt it be in hour and mins format?

Comment: `setTime(Date date)` accepts Date object it should be proper date. Use `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` format on it, it will work, so you will understand.

Comment: simpleDateFormat1 i have already used this format ("dd/MM/yyyy"). Am i supposed to change this format of ("HH:mm") to ("dd/MM/yyyy")?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned couple of times, if you want to use setTime() it accepts a proper Date object. (HH:mm) won't give you proper date.

Comment: Erm..i converted them but i will receive the following error. 2020-10-25 18:32:05.715 8904-8904/com.example.cleanerapp W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10:30"

Comment: I think the format is working fine. Somehow the codes i am not too sure whether they overlapped. As stated above, if i placed the codes for time validation above  of the date validation, the time will be printed out but the date will not

Comment: I just noted I would not faced any error if i have both input value at the same time before clicking the button to print them. But if i only have one input value in one of the field, it will display the error. I am not too sure why are they linked

Comment: @AXIES This is first thing I asked you in comment to check if it is empty, to which you replied its not. I think you still not getting all points.